# ng-repeat doesn't work on multidimonsional array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object

I have the following array and following code but im stuck. The ng-repeat is not working on this array(for other scopes it works good). I am  missing something, but i cant figure out what it is.

Example msgArray (array is created dynamically, i copied this from browser console)

```
[john: Array[0], Carl: Array[2]]
```

html Code

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='(k, v) in msgArray'>{{ k }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an array, but an object with array properties.  The `(k, v)` syntax of ng-repeat iterates over each property of the object with `k` as the key and `v` as the value.  If you want to display the *first* element of each value, you would do something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, v) in msgArray">{{ v[0] }}</li>
```

You can also `ng-repeat` over `v` (or "messages" if you want to be more explicit) if you need to do that as well.  Note that you only need the `(k, v)` syntax if you actually want to use the key.

```
<li ng-repeat="messages in msgArray">
    <span ng-repeat="msg in messages">{{msg}}</span>
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jnnvYxVCiHOEnkU4b2Iv?p=preview

[Also see the `ng-repeat` documentation on this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

Comment: Seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/jnnvYxVCiHOEnkU4b2Iv?p=preview there may be another problem with your code that is not present in your question